# Is eclipse 3.6 compatible for google apps?

Tags: eclipse

Is eclipse 3.6 compatible for google apps? If not then what are the versions compatible for google apps.Let me know the latest versions which are stable to use for google apps.Can i know more about stable versions of google apps and eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Google Web Toolkit & Google App Engine plugin is compatible with Eclipse 3.6.

See code.google.com for more details.

.PMCD.

Comment: is it a stable one?or is this in lab?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Eclipse 3.6 is fully compatible and that goes both for coding in Java and Python. For Python you need to install the PyDev plugin though.

Here is Googles article on the subject:
http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html#Download_the_Google_Plugin_for_Eclipse

And in there there is lots of info for both Java and Python too.

Comment: As far as I can see they are at 1.3.8 (http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html#Download_the_Google_App_Engine_SDK)